# How to Remove native android style in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

[image][image]I am developing a application using Ionic.In my application i used drop-down.when i build and test app in android device the drop-down open like pop-up.i came to know that it is device specific style.how can i remove that style.
Thanks in advance.I want to work drop-down like 1st image but now it works as a second image in android mobile.

Here is my drop-down code snippet.

Comment: <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

Comment: You can use your own css over it .

Comment: http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/vnzem

Comment: even i put my css but it will take device specific style for drop-down can you please suggest css for that.

Comment: go through the codepen link , i have sent you .. maybe thats what you need :)

Comment: just now i attached screen shot of app.still it shows drop-down like a pop-up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124902/discussion-between-manoj-rejinthala-and-ujjwal-kaushik).

Answer (score 0):

Use Your Select Inside list div.

```
<div class="list">
 <label class="item item-input item-select">
  <select> 
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> 
   <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option> 
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
 </label>
</div>
```

Hope It helps you (y) Thanks

Comment: Ujjwal kaushik even i include in the list also it open up like a pop-up

Answer (score 0):

For my personal experience using ionic, there are styles that was defined in the css file that are specific to Android platforms class, for example

```
.platform-android .popover {
  margin-top: -32px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35); }
```

You can test your app with Chrome's inspector (if you device has android >4.4 version) and find the style that are applied to that element.